# C# Organize variables?

Tags: c#

In C# is there a way to make something similar to a struct that is only created when new instances of an object are created? Here is an example. I want people to be able to assign events, the problem is that there are a lot of events to assign, and often they have similar functionality, just for a different object. For example, a left button down event, right button down event, etc. etc. I thought I could organize all these with structs but, I ran into a snag when I found that structs where considered "static" and not able to access non-static members. Is there any sort of structure that would let me do this in C#.

(The end result should let me make a new object, and assign to this objects event through these structures)

```
MouseObject mouse  = new MouseObject();

mouse.Left.PressedEvent += somemethod();
```

In this example Left cannot be a struct since it is used in a non-static instance.

Comment: Your question is very confused (or confusing). Structs aren't considered static - indeed, the concept doesn't even make sense. Your code certainly *could* be made to compile, although it wouldn't be a good idea. I see no reason to use a struct here - you should really read up about the differences between structs and classes.

Comment: When you sasy "structs are static", did you define the `Left` struct inside your `MouseObject` class?  If you actually create an instance of your struct, it won't be "static" (unless you define the instance using the `static` keyword).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use another class?

```
class MouseButton
{
    public SomeEvent PressedEvent;
}

class MouseObject
{
    public MouseButton Left { get; }
    public MouseButton Right { get; }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how I missed this, I was trying to put my struct inside the MouseObject class. Derp. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

[Mutable structs are evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil).  If you make it with structs, as below, it runs, but the `PressedEvent` never gets my handler, presumably because the struct I'm modifying isn't the one that's really in `MouseObject`.  Go with a class, as in @japreiss's solution.

```
struct MouseButton
{
    internal void OnPressed()
    {
        if (PressedEvent != null)
            PressedEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    public event EventHandler PressedEvent;
    public event EventHandler ReleasedEvent;
}
class MouseObject
{
    public MouseButton Left { get; private set; }
    public MouseButton Right { get; private set; }
    public void OnLeftPressed()
    {
        Left.OnPressed();
    }
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var m = new MouseObject();
    m.Left.PressedEvent += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("pressed");
    m.OnLeftPressed();
}
```

This prints `it was null!`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is the code you used.

```
public class MouseObject
{
    public struct Left
    {
        public event EventHandler PressedEvent;
    }
}
```

In this case, `Left` is not a member of MouseObject. It is just another type. This kind of encapsulation behaves much like namespaces.

What you probably intended was something like this:

```
public class MouseObject
{
    public MouseButton Left { get; set; }

    // Left still needs to be intialized, preferably in the constructor
}

public class MouseButton
{
    public event EventHandler PressedEvent;
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's it. I'm not entirely sure why I thought that would work.